# sbt compiles fine but IntelliJ shows errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a simple Scala project, created in IntelliJ as a sbt project.  After I manually copied in some jars to `lib/`, IntelliJ can't compile the project or find those dependencies.  sbt works fine.

I believe, though I unfortunately didn't record, that even before those libs, sbt could compile but IntelliJ can't.

How can I configure IntelliJ to use sbt internally (and not their Make), or do whatever is else needed to get IntelliJ to find dependencies and compile, when sbt works fine?

(Using: IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2, sbt 0.13, project was created via IntelliJ as sbt project.  IntelliJ is reading the sbt managed dependencies,and shows them in External Libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any way to have Intellij use SBT in the background.

Have you considered installing the jars to a [local maven repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)  then [adding the local maven repo as a resolver](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) and using the jars as managed dependencies?

I'm assuming of course that these extra jars are not available via an existing public repo.